# Kotlin: idiomatic way to map a list of objects to a list of values from one field?

Tags: collections, kotlin, functional-programming

I map a list of objects to a list of the value of one of the fields of the objects.

In this case, the variable `languages` is a `List<Language>` where the class `Language` has a field `code` that is of type `String`:

```
val languageCodes:List<String> = languages.map { language -> language.code }
```

Is there a more idiomatic and/or concise way to do this (except to omit the type of the list, which I left in this example for the sake of clarity)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You more or less have it. To make it a bit clearer, you could eliminate `language` in favor of `it`, the default name of a single argument to a lambda:

```
val languageCodes = languages.map { it.code }
```

But what you have would work just as well, and is probably about as clear (this is subjective). You'll notice I named my val "`languageCodes`", as your reuse of `languages` wouldn't compile.

Comment: Nice! I just found out about this keyword too. And nicely spotted the error with the languages... in my original code the languages collection was a field of another object.

Answer (score 0):

I found about the `it` [keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) that refers to an implicit single parameter of a lambda:

```
val languageCodes:List<String> = languages.map { it.code }
```

Pretty neat!

Quoting the official doc:

*It's very common that a lambda expression has only one parameter.
If the compiler can figure the signature out itself, it is allowed not to declare the only parameter and omit `->`. The parameter will be implicitly declared under the name `it`.*